# Can I change NavigationController settings from custom view class

Tags: swift, swift3

Can I change NavigationController settings from custom view class?

```
import UIKit

class TutorialView: UIView {
  init() {
    //change navigation controller settings
    //ex: navigationController.navigationItem.title = "hoge"
  }
}
```

I know this way. However my app rootViewController is TabBarController. NavigationController on TabBarController.

```
(window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController)?.navigationItem.title = "hoge"
```

In what way is it best to change NavigationController settings?

Answer (score 0):

`ViewControllers`s `viewDidLoad` Method is the right place, IMO, to change any properties of the NavigationController, as long as they are specific to that view. These include title color, large title display setting, etc...
If you want to change/add NavigationController methods, like implement a new pushViewController method, then I would suggest you subclass `UINavigationController` and override the necessary properties/methods.
If you want to change the  navigationBar appearance, you can do that from your AppDelegate, see [this](https://sarunw.com/posts/uinavigationbar-changes-in-ios13/).